# android get image URL from firebase storage

Tags: java, android, url, firebase-storage

This is my code for getting the URL for an image in Firebase Storage.  It's getting errors in the LOG file about Google Play Services, but they are defined in the Gradle file.  Any thoughts?

**CODE:**

```
private void getURL(String team) {
    Log.i(TAG, ">>>>>  getURL: " + team);

    URL = "";
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();
    StorageReference pathReference = storageRef.child("images/" + Pearadox.FRC_Event + "/robot_" + team.trim() + ".png");
    Log.e(TAG, "images/" + Pearadox.FRC_Event + "/robot_" + team.trim() + ".png" + "\n \n");

    pathReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            Log.e(TAG, "uri: " + uri.toString());
            URL = uri.toString();
        }
    });
    Log.w(TAG, "URL: " + URL);
```

GRADLE:

```
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
  compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:0.6.0'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
```

**ERROR:**

>

> 03-28 17:04:15.500 19549-19549/com.pearadox.scout_5414 I/Visualizer_Activity: >>>>>  getURL: 5414
>   03-28 17:04:15.500 19549-21086/com.pearadox.scout_5414 I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.firebasestorage:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.firebasestorage:0
>   03-28 17:04:15.500 19549-19549/com.pearadox.scout_5414 E/Visualizer_Activity: images/txho/robot_5414.png
>
> 03-28 17:04:15.500 19549-19549/com.pearadox.scout_5414 W/Visualizer_Activity: URL: 
>   03-28 17:04:15.500 19549-21086/com.pearadox.scout_5414 E/NetworkRqFactoryProxy: NetworkRequestFactoryProxy failed with a RemoteException:
>                                                                                  com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$zza: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
>                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbre.(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbre.zzj(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                      at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzaaN(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                      at com.google.firebase.storage.zzb.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>                                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>   03-28 17:04:15.501 19549-21086/com.pearadox.scout_5414 E/GetMetadataTask: Unable to create firebase storage network request.
>                                                                            android.os.RemoteException
>                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbre.(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbre.zzj(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzaaN(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                at com.google.firebase.storage.zzb.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>                                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>   03-28 17:04:15.501 19549-21087/com.pearadox.scout_5414 E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gms.chimera
>   03-28 17:04:15.501 19549-21087/com.pearadox.scout_5414 W/DynamiteModule: Failed to retrieve remote module version.

[Storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76Xr2.jpg)